# debian preseed select smallest drive for OS

Tags: debian-buster

So in my case I have a box with 2 drives 1 SSD small , usually 120 Gb and the rest bigger 500 or bigger, I need the OS always to be installed in the smallest drive and the second one to be left for data side.

Is there a way to detect the smallest drive and then do all there ?

Thanks.

Comment: While install process Question is asked to you to choose partitions, so you might use SSD as system drive (/) & bigger one to (/app or /opt or /home) depending or your needs.   If you wiish to automate the installation  you just do the same partition plan in the files. You identify disks & capacity from device informations sda/sdb/etc....

Comment: Well that was the idea, to have all automated , so far it takes the biggest drive as OS and left one is left empty, so I needed to be separate drives separate partitions. while li found this d-i partman/early_command string \
  PRIMARYDISK=$(lsblk -lbn --output SIZE,NAME | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -d" " -f2);\
  debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$PRIMARYDISK"; as option this selects the biggest drive so opposite to  what I need , then how do I get the smallest one ?

Comment: I think it is about using partman-base templates:
Template: partman/early_command
it is Type: string
the  Description: for internal use; can be preseeded
with a  Shell command or commands to run immediately before partitioning

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your comment, I know what that does, the issue is how to select the smallest drive, that's all rest all is taken care of . thanks

Answer (score 0):

To select the smallest drive you can use a preseed snippet like

```
d-i partman/early_command string \
  PRIMARYDISK=/dev/$(lsblk -Sn -o NAME --sort SIZE --include 8 | head -n 1) ; \
  debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$PRIMARYDISK" ;
```

The command `lsblk -Sn -o NAME --sort SIZE --include 8 | head -n 1` should select the smallest SCSI disk, but may need to be modified depending on the hardware.

**Links**

- [Preseed Advanced Options](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/apbs05.en.html) has an example using `list-devices`
- [More complex solutions in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707327/use-preseed-to-chose-install-disks-based-on-size-or-type)

Comment: My friend you deserve an entry in the debconf hall of fame. This is as obscure and useful as it gets.